# iOS mail app is deleting a background image on dark mode

Tags: html, css, ios, frontend, darkmode

I'm struggling with an issue related to a background image, I made a Litmus testing and all the devices including iOS on its normal mode are rendering the bg image properly, but when I reviewed and sent a test the dark mode for the apple mail, the image is gone and this is happening in all iOS devices. Here some reference images:

| iOS Dark Mode issue | iOS Light Mode without issue |
| --- | --- |
| [image: iOS Dark mode issue] | [image: iOS Light version without issue] |

And the code I'm using for this is:

```
<td align="center" background="imagehere.png" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="widthFull" height="250" style="background-image: url('imagehere.png'); background-position: center center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 600px; height: 250px;" valign="top" width="600">
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thank you!